# Где можно узнать, какие классы поддерживаются в урезанных кроссплатформенных версиях .NET, а какие нет?

Tags: .net-standard, спецификация

Мне удалось найти информацию о том, что `System.IO`, `System.Collections` и `System.Xml` поддерживаются везде. Про Linq вроде бы тоже мелькала информация, что он там есть.

Но в основном всё, что мне попадается по этой теме, посвящено концепции, что такое .NET Standard как таковой, а конкретики очень мало. Пишут, что есть какие-то спецификации, но непонятно, где их найти, более того, боюсь, в спецификациях этой конкретики будет, наоборот, слишком много, так что я всё равно из них ничего не пойму, утонув в деталях.

Меня интересуют следующие вещи.

1. Сериализация - `XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter`, `DataContractSerializer`
2. Interop, прежде всего, `DllImport` и связанные с ним вещи типа `MarshalAs` или `StructLayout`. Если там такого нет (что было бы логично, т.к. dll - это чисто виндовое решение), то должно же быть тогда что-то, напоминающее `JNI` в Java?
3. Компоненты сущностей ADO.NET - `DataSet` и всё, из чего он состоит, интерфейсы управляемых поставщиков.
4. Что там для работы с сетью? Сокеты хотя бы есть?
5. Что там есть для разработки GUI? Хотя бы `System.Drawing`?
6. Есть ли там моя любимая `System.ComponentModel`?
7. Стандартный конфигуратор? app.config, Settings.settings и прочее.
8. Класс `ReaderWriterLockSlim`? В отличие от других классов для работы с потоками, он в отдельной библиотеке .NET Framework.
9. Классы `System.Diagnostics.Process` и `System.Environment`?

Возможно, ещё что-то забыл, но это вот основное.

Comment: В описании конкретного класса, который хотите использовать, смотрите раздел [Applies to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.arrayconverter?view=netcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to) внизу. Вряд ли можно придумать что-то лучше.

Comment: Можете конвертировать в ответ? Скорее всего, это и есть исчерпывающий ответ на мой вопрос. Хотя, например, здесь есть неплохая картинка, содержащая интересующую меня информацию: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-net-standard-2/ Но откуда она взялась?

Comment: Когда выходит (или только готовится к выходу) новая версия языка/платформы/фреймворка и т. п., всегда публикуются материалы наподобие [Announcing .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/), [Announcing .NET Standard 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/) - из них и собирается информация для таких картинок/табличек.